# Intent and Serialization in DevEco

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos, deveco-studio

While creating a user info card in DevEco Studio we need to begin with empty ability or anything else ? If we begin with empty ability , there's already an intent present, creating a new one shows error !

Comment: Hey Rohan, Can you please provide more information on the above? Show us some code what you have tried and error (attach logs from stack trace if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow [this](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ability-service-widget-provider-intro-0000001150722105) official documentation to develop service widget.

[image]

If the problem persists, please provide error logs during service widget creation for us to check.

Answer (score 0):

All applications start with main Ability and the UI is handled in Ability Slice.
Also refer these developer links for more information, if you have more concerns, lets have a call and discuss

https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ability-ability-overview-0000000000029852
https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/ui-java-overview-0000000000500404

Reference as answered:
https://github.com/applibgroup/HarmonyOS-Knowledgebase/issues/79

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).